# EXCEL VBA error message datatypes incompatible reading the value of a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I aske more or less the same question as recently in German.

I have a workbook with several worksheets that contain several cells with numeric content,
there are numbers with at least 3 decimal places,
Therefore I first cose Double as the data type, which amazes me that I got an error message when I start the debugger for the SUB "Startnahe"
in single step mode
immediately get for the line in which I try to read the cell conten v and the debugger got stuck in this line,
now I delared v and d, s, dl as Varian, the result
is alas that debugger give me the same error message but in the line later,
where I calculate d = s - v.

```
Public Function Nahe(ZelleSuchWert As Variant, TabName)
  Dim rw As Integer
  Dim cl As String
  Dim c As Range
  Dim v As Variant
  Dim s As Variant, d As Variant, dl As Variant
  Dim i As Integer, a As Integer
  Dim Liste As Worksheet
  
  Set Liste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TabName)
  If (Liste Is Nothing) Then
    Nahe = "No hay tabla de este nombre"
    Exit Function
  Else
    cl = Left(ZelleSuchWert, 1)
    rw = CInt(Right(ZelleSuchWert, 2))
    Set c = Liste.Cells(rw, cl)
    If (c Is Nothing) Then
      Nahe = "No esta instanciado celdula-obj"
      Exit Function
    Else
      s = c.Value
      With Liste
        i = 1
        dl = 360
        a = 0
        Do While (Not IsEmpty(Liste.Cells(i, 1)))
          v = Liste.Cells(i, 1).Value
          
          d = s - v 'error datatype incompatible
          If d < dl Then
            dl = d
            a = i
          Else
            Exit Do 'maximal aproximada encontrado
          End If
          i = i + 1
        Loop
        Nahe = .Cells(a, 2)
      End With
    End If
  End If
End Function

Public Sub StartNahe()
  Dim r As String
  r = Nahe("E11", "Rosa_Brujula")
End Sub
```

Or do I have a buck in there that has nothing to do with the cell content?
"Rosa_Brujula is a worksheet, with 2 columnes in the 1st column
there is a value,
with 2 decimale places
in the 2nd column there is a string which should be behind the cell after the cell to be read out.

If the decimal places should be a problem, then it will be difficult;
because the cell to be read contains an angle that is determined trigonometrically
and which can have decimal places.

I have Excel 10 in a German installation.

Comment: What's the datatype of `s` and `v` in the local window? perhaps try `d = CDbl(s) - CDbl(v)`

Comment: Tried your problem, but since you did not provide actual data from the ws "Rosa_Brujula" I invented my own, that the code expects. No error. Please edit your question and add actual data for "E11" and "A1..Bnn"

Comment: This is the content of Rosa_Brujula, the 1st columne has a number, with 3 decimals the 2n a String, and my code should find the line most close to a numeric value also with 3 decimals.

Comment: S and v are numeric also with 3 decimals.

Comment: The numeric values in Rosa_Brujula runs from 0 to 360,000